# How python handle DNS resolution with Tor Relay?

Tags: python, dns, tor

Supposing this working code :

```
import win_inet_pton
import socks
import socket
s = socks.socksocket()
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "localhost", 9050)
s.connect(("xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion",80))
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
print 'sended'
data=s.recv(1024)
print data
```

Tor service is indeed running at port 9050.

In normal condition, python will perform DNS resolution through the SOCKS5 proxy, which is connected to the Tor relay. However, Tor do not handle UDP packet(It handles the resolution directly from the hostname in the TCP packet) so DNS resolution will fail.

How is it possible that this code work? (the equivalent code in java for exemple will fail as the DNS resolution can't be made).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests

Comment: @tripleee Sorry but I don't think this is a Cross-site duplicate. The thing I want to point is that code work only in python. If you try this with other programming langage, I think the DNS resolution is made through the proxy, will fail and will close the socket. This is a normal process for proxy/socket implementation to perform DNS resolution through the proxy. So I'm wondering why it's working in python..Also, the process here is different as I'm trying to connect to an onion domain (there is no notion of exit node perfoming DNS resolution if you try to connect to an hidden service).

Answer (score -1):

IT is explained in this link: [Python requests fails when tryign to connect to .onion site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338274/python-requests-fails-when-tryign-to-connect-to-onion-site)
You simply have to use `socks5h` instead of `socks5`