# Python requests fails when tryign to connect to .onion site

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get a webpage which is hosted in the tor network. I'm using the following code:

```
import requests

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}
    return session

session = get_tor_session()
```

When I try to get a normal website it works fine, for example: `print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)` prints `{"origin": "80.67.172.162"}`

But when I try it on a .onion site, it fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 813, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 477, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 540, in _SOCKS5_request
    resolved = self._write_SOCKS5_address(dst, writer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socks.py", line 592, in _write_SOCKS5_address
    addresses = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spider.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(session.get("http://zqktlwi4fecvo6ri.onion/").text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='zqktlwi4fecvo6ri.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.contri
b.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x106fd62e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `socks5` scheme, domains are resolved locally by the client's DNS server. But 'normal' DNS servers can't resolve .onion domains and so your request fails.

From [docs.python-requests.org](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#socks):

> Using the scheme `socks5` causes the DNS resolution to happen on the client, rather than on the proxy server. This is in line with curl, which uses the scheme to decide whether to do the DNS resolution on the client or proxy. If you want to resolve the domains on the proxy server, use `socks5h` as the scheme.

So, in order to connect to .onion sites you should let TOR resolve the domain. This is possible if you use the `socks5h` sheme in the proxies dictionary.

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150', 'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'}
response = session.get("https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/")
print(response)
#<Response [200]>
```

Note that you may have to install extra dependencies.

```
pip install requests[socks]
```

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, hope you are doing well. I came across a serious issue which I can't resolve myself, so I thought to bother you a bit. Here is the [post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60163181/cant-scrape-names-from-next-pages-using-requests) .Thanks in advance.