# Can't scrape names from next pages using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, http-post

I'm trying to parse names traversing multiple pages from a webpage using a python script. With my current attempt I can get the names from it's landing page. However, I can't find any idea to fetch the names from next pages as well using requests and BeautifulSoup.

[website link](https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95)

My attempt so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    for elem in soup.select("table#gvContractors tr:has([id*='_lblName'])"):
        name = elem.select_one("span[id*='_lblName']").get_text(strip=True)
        print(name)
```

I've tried to modify my script to get only the content from the second page to make sure it is working when there is a next page button involved but unfortunately it still fetches data from the first page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = 'Page$Next'
    payload.pop('btnClose')
    payload.pop('btnMapClose')
    res = s.post(url,data=payload,headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'Referer': 'https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95',
        })
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for elem in sauce.select("table#gvContractors tr:has([id*='_lblName'])"):
        name = elem.select_one("span[id*='_lblName']").get_text(strip=True)
        print(name)
```

Comment: You can get the link to the next page url and make next request

Comment: That's an unchanging url, so I doubt there is any next page url  having different look @Eternal .

Comment: I checked the site and it seems the pagination is javascript driven. You need to find a way to click the next button. Maybe use selenium

Comment: I've used selenium and found success. Initiating click on the next page button to fetch the content from next pages is an old news. However, I've created this post to find any solution using requests module in combination with BeautifulSoup library. Thanks.

Comment: If there are actions performed using javascript and websites that heavily depend upon javascript then it is nearly impossible to do so. However, you can inspect the website and analyse network tab to see what ajax calls are being made. Or if you are lucky you will be able to find API.

Comment: you can scrape the next URL from Html and made another request for that. if it is possible in your case means anywhere in Html dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating to next page is being performed via POST request with __VIEWSTATE cursor.

How you can do it with requests:

1. Make GET request to first page;
2. Parse required data and __VIEWSTATE cursor;
3. Prepare POST request for next page with received cursor;
4. Run it, parse all data and new cursor for next page.

I won't provide any code, because it requires to write down almost all crawler's code.

==== Added ====

You almost done it, but there are two important things you have missed.

1. It is necessary to send headers with first GET request. If there're no headers sent - we get broken tokens (it is easy to detect visually - they haven't == at the end)
2. We need to add **__ASYNCPOST** to payload we send. (It is very interesting: it is not a boolean True, it is a string 'true')

Here's code. I removed bs4 and added lxml (i don't like bs4, it is very slow). We exactly  know which data we need to send, so let's parse only few inputs.

```
import re
import requests
from lxml import etree


def get_nextpage_tokens(response_body):
    """ Parse tokens from XMLHttpRequest response for making next request to next page and create payload """
    try:
        payload = dict()
        payload['ToolkitScriptManager1'] = 'UpdatePanel1|gvContractors'
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'gvContractors'
        payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = 'Page$Next'
        payload['__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'] = ''
        payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = re.search(r'__VIEWSTATE\|([^\|]+)', response_body).group(1)
        payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = re.search(r'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR\|([^\|]+)', response_body).group(1)
        payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = re.search(r'__EVENTVALIDATION\|([^\|]+)', response_body).group(1)
        payload['__ASYNCPOST'] = 'true'
        return payload
    except:
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95"

    headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Referer': 'https://proximity.niceic.com/mainform.aspx?PostCode=YO95',
            }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        page_num = 1
        r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.fromstring(r.text, parser)

        # Creating payload
        payload = dict()
        payload['ToolkitScriptManager1'] = 'UpdatePanel1|gvContractors'
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'gvContractors'
        payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = 'Page$Next'
        payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = tree.xpath("//input[@name='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")[0]
        payload['__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED'] = ''
        payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = tree.xpath("//input[@name='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")[0]
        payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = tree.xpath("//input[@name='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value")[0]
        payload['__ASYNCPOST'] = 'true'
        headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'

        while True:
            page_num += 1
            res = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

            print(f'page {page_num} data: {res.text}')  # FIXME: Parse data

            payload = get_nextpage_tokens(res.text)  # Creating payload for next page
            if not payload:
                # Break if we got no tokens - maybe it was last page (it must be checked)
                break
```

***Important***

Response not a well formed HTML. So You have to deal with it: cut table or something else. Good luck!

Comment: You updated your question and have almost done it. I make some changes to Your code and add it as update to my answer. There are some issues You have to deal with

Comment: This is something that I don't come across very frequently. It's an awesome approach. I've one little question on this though. I still don't find any logic how to go on to the next page as you know `Page$Next` portion is always the same no matter how many pages I traverse. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: You need to parse token from response after each request, because you need to send actual cursor to server. I've updated code. I parse them via regular expressions. But if you "deserialize" response while parsing tables - may be yo can do it without regexes.

Comment: I have same problem. after pass every viewstate and other form values for next requests, there is only pages 1 - 10 response . when request to page 11 ,response back to page 1